# How to replace a string inside a Linux shared library (.so) by a longer string?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I have a .so library and I want to replace a string hardcoded inside it by another one which is longer in its length. Is it possible?

Comment: It could be possible, if the strings are aligned to more than a `char` address. Then there might be a few unused bytes you could change without breaking anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the source and can recompile the library: fine. go for it.

If you mean via a hex editor or similar: Very dangerous to try.
Adding one char might work depending on how much padding etc is applied (possibly none, so even adding 1 char will break). The more you add the more chance it will fail.

Assuming "without source", I think the real answer is "No".

Comment: For the sake of information to future readers, I checked your answer as the correct one since indeed there's no way on doing this without having the source files. In the end my solution was workaround the issue using interposition of functions, but my case was very specific. Thanks :)

Comment: As I said, it is possible - in my case we had a directory path `/abc/` that we needed to change to `/xyz/` - hex edit worked fine because string length matched. Changing long to short might work (no guarantees), but short to long is pretty much a no!

Answer (score 1):

If the variable has a symbol and is always looked up by it, you could LD_PRELOAD a small library that just exports that symbol.

Alternatively, for a oneshot technique, you could load the program under gdb and set it (which will implicitly malloc a string for you).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but it isn't easy. (I've done similar things using each of the approaches below).

Option 1: Sometimes, the string that follows the target string isn't used, or isn't very commonly used. For example, it might be an error message string. In that case, you can just write over it, and hope that whatever used that string isn't going to break if it sees something else (namely, the tail end of your new string).

Option 2: You can use a disassembler (like IDA) to locate uses of the string in the program, and rewrite those to point at a new region of the binary. Then you can write your new string in that new area. This isn't nearly as bad as you might think, especially if you have a good disassembler that can show you references to the data section.